# NoMethodError in Shops::RegistrationsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I noticed that I had a typo regarding a `column_name` in a `table` and I changed it. Also, I changed all the code and `params` that is associated with the `column`.

I changed `buisness_name` to `business_name` and now I'm getting this error:

```
NoMethodError in Shops::RegistrationsController#create 
undefined method `buisness_name' for #<Account:0x007fd2f259cac8> Did you mean? business_name business_name= business_name?
```

This is create method where the error occurs, at the line were to says `resource.save`:

```
def create
     cookies[:email] = {:value => params[:shop][:email],
                        :domain => :all, :expires => 1.hour.from_now}
     build_resource(sign_up_params)

     resource.save
    yield resource if block_given?
     if resource.persisted?
       if resource.active_for_authentication?
        flash[:notice] = 'Successfully signed up'
         respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
       else
         flash[:notice] = "Signed up but #{resource.inactive_message}"
         expire_data_after_sign_in!
         respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
       end
     else
       clean_up_passwords resource
       set_minimum_password_length
       respond_with resource
     end
   end
```

I even restarted the server and still the error appears. I have no idea why this is happening...

Comment: Yes I did... what is even more weird is that inside `schema.rb` its correct: `t.string "business_name"`

Comment: `undefined method 'buisness_name' for #<Account:0x007fd2f259cac8>`
This means its still trying to do object.buisness_name somewhere and complaining that no method name buisness_name exists on Account class.

Comment: where is resource getting assigned ?  does `build_resource(sign_up_params)` return resource ?

Comment: I got it now @Vbp.... I forgot to change the validations inside the model.